# enf of file unexpected (excepting "f$ing "fi")

Tags: shell-script, csh

```
os: pfSense (nanobsd)
shell: csh
```

script:

```
/etc/rc.conf_mount_rw
mount -t msdosfs /dev/da0s1 /mnt/usb

if ( -s /var/squid/log/access.log ) then
    cat /var/squid/log/access.log | perl -p -e 's/^([0-9]*)/"[".localtime($1)."]"/e' > /mnt/usb/access_`date +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M`.log
    echo "Log wurde gespeichert"
else
    echo "Logfile ist leer, kein Logfile geschrieben"
endif

/etc/rc.conf_mount_ro
```

Throws following error:

```
/scripts/copy-script.sh: 14: Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting "f$ing "fi")
```

Any Suggestions?

Comment: As a general suggestion, you should write your maintenance scripts in `sh` syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the shebang line at the beginning of your script.

```
#!/bin/csh
```

So that it will be executed with the `/bin/csh` and not with the `/bin/sh`.

The error looks like your script is executed with `sh`.

Answer (score 0):

`if` statements should end with `fi`, not with `endif`.

Comment: Throws following error: fi: Command not found. , or could it be possible that i am using the normal shell?, when i write $SHELL it says sh and $shell brings csh

Comment: @hsos, Sorry, you were right to begin with. `csh` doesn't use standard shell syntax.

Comment: The problem was that the default shell without a shebang was the normal shell.
I have added `#!/bin/csh -f`
to force the c-shell.